# Unable to read data from a database after copying external database into internal android database

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-sqlite

I've tried to copy external database into phone's db using the following code

```
    /**
     * Populates database with existing database.
     */
    fun installDatabaseFromAssets() {
        val inputStream = context.assets.open("$ASSETS_PATH/$DATABASE_NAME.sqlite3")

        try {
            val outputFile = File(context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).path)
            val outputStream = FileOutputStream(outputFile)

            inputStream.copyTo(outputStream)
            inputStream.close()

            outputStream.flush()
            outputStream.close()
        } catch (exception: Throwable) {
            throw RuntimeException("The $DATABASE_NAME database couldn't be installed.", exception)
        }
    }
```

as explained in https://medium.com/@johann.pardanaud/ship-an-android-app-with-a-pre-populated-database-cd2b3aa3311f . I've also renamed my sqlite db id column to `_ID` as recommended in the article. The data gets copied fine, but when I try to read it using the app, it throws the following errors

```
01-23 16:36:13.808 31146-31165/com.lonewolf.rj.myapp E/CursorWindow: Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 19407 rows, 8 columns.
01-23 16:36:13.808 31146-31165/com.lonewolf.rj.myapp W/dalvikvm: threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41632d58)
01-23 16:36:13.808 31146-31165/com.lonewolf.rj.myapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.lonewolf.rj.myapp, PID: 31146
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
        at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
        at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:437)
        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
        at com.lonewolf.rj.myapp.DatabaseHelper.readData(DatabaseHelper.kt:101)
        at com.lonewolf.rj.myapp.MainActivity$DbWork.doInBackground(MainActivity.kt:46)
        at com.lonewolf.rj.myapp.MainActivity$DbWork.doInBackground(MainActivity.kt:42)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

How can I fix this issue and my make the written database readable? and if there are any android specific columns that should exist in the db?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

I'd suggest to check whether the database fields are written correctly as it could be case sensitive this time.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the Steps
 1. Copy Database from internal storage and create same DB name file in external storage
 2. Now after check if external storage is exist copy database and move to internal storage

copyDataBseToExternal(
          internalDBFilePath,
            DB_NAME,
            ExternalDBFilePath
        )

copyDataBseFromExternal(
                   ExternalDBFilePath,
                    DB_NAME,
                    InternalDbFilePath
                )

//Copy DB From SD card to Internal App Folder

fun copyDataBseFromExternal(inputPath: String, inputFile: String, outputPath: String)

{

```
    var ins: InputStream? = null

    var out: OutputStream? = null

    try {
        //create output directory if it doesn't exist
        val dir = File(outputPath)
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs()
        }
        ins = FileInputStream(inputPath)
        out = FileOutputStream(outputPath)
        val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
        var length = ins.read(buffer)
        // read = `in`.read(buffer)
        while (length > 0) {
            //out.write(buffer, 0, read)
            out.write(buffer, 0, length)
            length = ins.read(buffer)
        }
        ins.close()

        // write the output file
        out.flush()
        out.close()
        // delete the original file
        // File(inputPath + inputFile).delete()
    } catch (fnfe1: FileNotFoundException) {
        Log.e("tag", fnfe1.message)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("tag", e.message)
    }
}
```

public fun copyDataBseToExternal(inputPath: String, inputFile: String, outputPath: String)

{

```
   var ins: InputStream? = null

    var out: OutputStream? = null

  try {
        //create output directory if it doesn't exist
        val dir = File(outputPath)
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs()
        }
        ins = FileInputStream(inputPath)
        out = FileOutputStream(outputPath + "/" + inputFile)
        val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
        var length = ins.read(buffer)
        // read = `in`.read(buffer)
        while (length > 0) {
            //out.write(buffer, 0, read)
            out.write(buffer, 0, length)
            length = ins.read(buffer)
        }
        ins.close()

        // write the output file
        out.flush()
        out.close()
        // delete the original file
        // File(inputPath + inputFile).delete()
    } catch (fnfe1: FileNotFoundException) {
        Log.e("tag", fnfe1.message)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("tag", e.message)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Message

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
```

say **not found** column, if use `cursor.getColumnIndex("column_name")` getting **-1** if **column_name** not column in Cursor.

use **0** not `cursor.getColumnIndex("column_name")` gets column first in Cursor.

way to see all Cursor use `DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(cursor);` all goes to log.